# How to Fix the 'set is undefined' error from the following code? Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is the code that I used. Basically I am making command handler in my bot after discord.js v13 released. After running the code it shows some error(set is undefined).

---

command.js

```js
const {readdirSync} = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table')
let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading('Command', ' Load status');
module.exports= (client) => {
    readdirSync('./commands/').forEach(dir => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for(let file of commands){
            let pull = require(`../commands/${dir}/${file}`);
            if(pull.name){
                client.commands.set(pull.name, command);
                table.addRow(file,'✅')
            } else {
                table.addRow(file, '❌ -> Missing a help.name, or help.name is not a string.')
                continue;
            }if(pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))
        }
    });
    console.log(table.toString());
}
```

The error image:

[image]

Comment: The error indicates that `client.commands` isn't defined, and you don't seem to be defining it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to define client, on top of your code add this:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
```

You have to also add intents since it's necessary in discord.js v13
Below add also this:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [
  "GUILDS",
  "GUILD_MEMBERS",
  ]
});
```

Here you have to specify your needed intents, you can find list of them here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS